# How to re-edit and/or duplicate an in-progress edit with YouTube Video Editor

Tags: youtube

After uploading a bunch of clips to YouTube, I go into their editor and begin making cuts, combining clips together, etc. The problem is, after I published it, there is no way (that I can see) to go back and open up that project in the Video Editor again to make changes to the edit.

This wouldn't be so bad if I also couldn't figure out how to duplicate an edit project. So for example, if Im in the middle of editing a bunch of clips together, named "Project 1", how could I think "Save as..." or duplicate that project to "Project 1b."

Any ideas? The google help center on this is pretty sparse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YouTube video editor is just not designed for this sort of thing - it has very basic functionality, just enough to allow you to tweak a couple of things. Once the edit is complete it has no ongoing concept of a 'project' - you just have a new video.

I would always recommend editing locally in a proper video editor and then uploading.

Comment: dang thats what i figured. its just so convenient to do it online and not fiddle with settings and stuff locally sometimes. for simple cuts, it has enough and the great thing about it is doesnt have a million options like final cut does (which inevitably gobbles up all my time as i get stuck playing with all the cool possibilities).

Comment: i will reluctantly check this as the correct answer, although, if youtube is ALREADY saving projects then that data struct is already there, so duplicating a project cant be hard to add... @YOUTUBE - please add this feature - duplicate projects!

Comment: I would imagine the problem is a scale issue - imagine storing every edited video project - you would have many times the storage space requirements.

Answer (score 0):

No copies of projects are yet possible on Youtube. I love the basic functionality of Youtube, straight to the point. Adobe Premiere makes it perfect, but woo! how much work and time and nonsense! Me too, I prefer it simple and basic most times. I sent a Feedback to Google to ask to add a couple of features in future. Fingers crossed. Ciao